# IOS: store in NSUSerdefault an array of object

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, nsuserdefaults

I have an array of object (custom object), it's called "favorite" and when I try to store this array in NSUserDefault i have this error

my code:

inside favorite -> (object1, object2, object3...) from class MyObject

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData* myClassArrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:favorite];
    [defaults setObject:myClassArrayData forKey:@"favorite"];
```

my error:

```
[MyObject encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317164/save-own-class-with-nscoder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659922/converting-a-nsobject-into-nsdata

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To store custom object, `MyObject` in your case, the class must implement the [`NSCoder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/Reference/NSCoder.html) interface.

The interface only has two methods:

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        self.identifier = [aDecoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"identifier"];
        self.name = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
        /* continue with all the properties that need to be restored  */

    }

    return self;
}

- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
     [aCoder encodeInteger:self.identifier forKey:@"identifier"];
     [aCoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"name"];
     /* continue with all the properties that need to be saved  */
}
```

Comment: that's a compilation issue. It wouldn't cause a unrecognized selector sent to instance error at runtime

Comment: In the error it is stated that `MyObject` does not recognize `encodeWithCoder:` which is one of the two methods you will need to implement to make you class conform the the `NSCoder` interface.

Comment: yes, you need to provide the methods. Whether or not you specify that your object conforms to the protocol only matters at compilation.

Comment: True, but the error clearly states that the class `MyObject` does not. So either the `favorite` variable is of type `MyObject` or it contains a property of type `MyObject`  which it is trying to encode. Either way the `MyObject` class does not comply to the `NSCoder` interface.

Comment: Yes, its working fine for me. First i wrongly implement these two methods in viewcontroller. Later i realize that implement in NSObject class. Thank you.