# Store temporary data in iOS

Tags: ios, store

I want to store data in iOS for globally, like session data in web. What is the best approach other than sqlite?

Comment: are you trying nsuserdefault

Comment: My purpose is to send data from one viewcontroller to other. Is that suitable. Is it better than delegating.

Comment: @Susitha NSUserDefaults is not what you want... On a website session data is used because there is no easy way to send data between webpages. In Objective-C you can pass data directly through methods.

Comment: @Susitha this is the wrie approch do dont worry...

Comment: @FaJitendraDeore to send data between VCs? No..

Comment: @Justin PAssing data between vc is possible using NSUserDefault...

Comment: @FaJitendraDeore yes many things are possible, but also cumbersome, inefficient, error prone, and nonsensical.

Comment: Actual problem is if i push viewcontroller and collect some data then come back to the previous view, how can i pass data to this view controller. Its like settings screen on ios device.

Comment: @Susitha when you push the view controller you can pass it all relevant data with a custom init or basic setters. When the child is done you can send the data to the parent with a delegate method or the parent can grab relevant data through getters.

Comment: @JustinMeiners thanks a lot. Could you give an example for send data to parent with a delegate method.

Comment: @Susitha https://gist.github.com/narpas/6102365 let me know if you want me to add more detail

Comment: Thanks @JustinMeiners. This is actually i am looking for. Is this the code for parent vc or child vc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34345/discussion-between-susitha-and-justin-meiners)

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSUserDefaults`.
NSUserDefaults is great for saving samm data like scores, login information, program state. You dont require database knowledge and its easy to learn and use.

Here is the documentation:
 http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Here is a good tutorial:
http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/

**Edit**:
Although, based on your comment it seems that you just want to pass data between ViewControllers.
**One way :**

Lets suppose you want to pass `NSString` `myString` from `ViewControllerA` to `ViewControllerB`.
Then create a property like this in `ViewControllerB`.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *passedString;// strong if you are using RC, ow retain
```

In `ViewControllerA.m` , when you are allocating, initiating `ViewControllerB`, then

```
ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc]init];
viewControllerB.passedString = myString;
```

**Another Way:** (more of a global variable type way)

You can declare a property in `AppDelegate.h`

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *passedString;
```

In ViewControllerB, you can create AppDelgate object and access the property:

```
AppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSString *passedString = app.passedString;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write basic types like `NSNumber`, `NSString`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, etc directly into the `NSUserDefaults`. These will be automatically saved/loaded between app sessions.

```
NSString* myData = @"someValue";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myData forKey:@"myData"];
```

For more complex data types you can take advantage of NSCoder and the NSCoding protocol to easily make your classes serializable.

The code in the answer here may be helpful.
[Save own Class with NSCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317164/save-own-class-with-nscoder)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` for that.

For saving data you can use this code

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:@"Dilip" forKey:@"firstName"];
    [defaults setObject:@"Manek" forKey:@"lastname"];
    [defaults setInteger:24 forKey:@"age"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

And for retrieving data use this code

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *firstName = [defaults objectForKey:@"firstName"];
    NSString *lastName = [defaults objectForKey:@"lastname"];
    int age = [defaults integerForKey:@"age"];
    NSString *ageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",age];
```

You can also store `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, or `NSData` as object in `NSUserDefault`.For more information take a look at [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/) tutorial.

another way to pass data Between viewController is like this.

Suppose we have Two ViewController

-FirstViewController

-SecondViewController

Now if i want to pass a string from First to second ViewController thanfirst create Property of that string in secondViewcontroller

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewcontroller : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *strFromFirst;
@end
```

Synthesize it in .m file. after that in firstViewController when you push view controller Send string to second Viewcontroller

```
SecondViewcontroller * vc = [[SecondViewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewcontroller" bundle:nil];

    // Pass the selected object to the SecondViewcontroller.
    fraudluntReportViewController.strFromFirst = @"Dilip";

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

This will send the string from FirstViewController to SecondViewController.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use NSUSERDefault its very easy to handle.

You can save NSString,NSDictionaray ,NSnumber in NSUserDefault like this..

// Store Array values

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:array forKey:@"array"];
```

// Stroe String to nsuserDefault

```
 NSString *str=@"ABC";
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:str forKey:@"value"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have limited data to store feel free to use `NSUserDefaults`.
[Apple Reference for NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

for example you need to store some string(say name) in to user defaults.

```
NSString *name = "Your Name";
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:name forKey:@"name"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

**IMPORTANT here is, once you done with setObject for key, you have to call `synchronize` method so that these changes get stored in User Defaults**

for accessing the same firstName string

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults objectForKey:@"name"];
```